# Cannot properly capture text needed

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm new to this and I was trying to write a spider using python, but I cannot get the part I need and I don't know where's wrong.
I pick out the part I need from the whole html file as below. I tried to use the RegEx `</tr[/s]*?>(<tr[\s]*?>.*?</tr[\s]*?>)<tr[/s]*?>`, but I got nothing. Is there anyone could help me fix this?

PS. I've already use sub to delete all the `\n` and the `\r` before I use findall to gather the info.

Thanks in advance.

```
</tr>
<tr >
    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;"  colspan='4' rowspan='1' >

<!-- START OBJECT-CELL -->

<table bgcolor='#C0C0C0' cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>

  <col align='left' />

  <col align='right' />

<tr>

  <td align='left' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font color='#000000'>AE1PGA/L1/01</font></td>

  <td align='right' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font color='#000000'>3-4</font></td>

</tr>

</table>

<table bgcolor='#C0C0C0' cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>

  <col align='center' />

<tr>

  <td align='center' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font color='#000000'>Programming And Algorithms</font></td>

</tr>

</table>

<table bgcolor='#C0C0C0' cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>

  <col align='left' />

<tr>

  <td align='left' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font color='#000000'></font></td>

</tr>

</table>

<!-- END OBJECT-CELL -->

    </td>

    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;"  colspan='4' rowspan='1' >

<!-- START OBJECT-CELL -->

<table bgcolor='#C0C0C0' cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>

  <col align='left' />

  <col align='right' />

<tr>

  <td align='left' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font color='#000000'>AE1MCS/L1/01</font></td>

  <td align='right' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font color='#000000'>3-5, 7-15</font></td>

</tr>

</table>

<table bgcolor='#C0C0C0' cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>

  <col align='center' />

<tr>

  <td align='center' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font color='#000000'>Mathematics For Computer Scientists</font></td>

</tr>

</table>

<table bgcolor='#C0C0C0' cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>

  <col align='left' />

<tr>

  <td align='left' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font color='#000000'>SEB-432+</font></td>

</tr>

</table>

<!-- END OBJECT-CELL -->

    </td>

</tr>
<tr >
```

Comment: Argh don't parse HTML yourself, use a library for this: beautifulsoup4: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4 (especially regex is a bad tool for the job)

Comment: @RvdK I've tried bs4, but it doesn't work properly either, so I have to do it myself

Comment: What about bs4 didn't work properly for you?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract from this HTML? What is your expected output?

Comment: @wilbur I tried to get the tag 'tr' but some 'tr' tags it gave me are in some other 'tr' tags.

Comment: That's likely if you use something like `soup.find_all('tr')` but it's much easier to filter through those `<tr>`s in bs4 than with regex

Comment: @MartinEvans What I post is just what I need, I've just pick them up from the whole html source file, and of course except the </tr> on the top and the <tr> at the end, I use these two in my RegEx so I just post them.

Comment: You say the RegEx in your question does not work, so we still do not know exactly what you are trying to extract. For example your aim might be to extract all of the text inside the TDs?

Comment: @MartinEvans I'd like to extract all things in the TR

Comment: @wilbur I tried but I got <tr>s in another <tr>s, so I have to do it myself

Comment: @Finger_5792: I am curious to know why you say Beautiful Soup doesn't work for you. Can you show the full HTML that you are trying to search? If it is too big then you can put it on [**pastebin**](http://pastebin.com) and link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copy the HTML you have posted into a string called `html`, the following script shows you how BeautifulSoup could help you to extract all of the `<tr>...</tr>` blocks:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        print tr
        print '-' * 30
```

This would display the following output:

```
<tr>
<td align="left" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font color="#000000">AE1PGA/L1/01</font></td>
<td align="right" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font color="#000000">3-4</font></td>
</tr>
------------------------------
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font color="#000000">Programming And Algorithms</font></td>
</tr>
------------------------------
<tr>
<td align="left" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font color="#000000"></font></td>
</tr>
------------------------------
<tr>
<td align="left" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font color="#000000">AE1MCS/L1/01</font></td>
<td align="right" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font color="#000000">3-5, 7-15</font></td>
</tr>
------------------------------
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font color="#000000">Mathematics For Computer Scientists</font></td>
</tr>
------------------------------
<tr>
<td align="left" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font color="#000000">SEB-432+</font></td>
</tr>
------------------------------
```

Note, the first `<tr>` is not displayed as the HTML you have posted does not contain the table it belongs to.

Comment: Thanks a million, that quite helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why your regex doesn't match the data you show

- You have `/s` in a couple of places where you mean `\s`
- You ask that the closin `</tr>` comes *immediately before* the opening `<tr>` in both cases, with no intervening space
- You're using a dot in `.*?` which doesn't match newlines unless you set the `DOTALL` option flag
- You're asking for three successive `<tr>` elements, which doesn't appear in your data

There'a also no need to put `[\s]` in brackets, but that won't affect the behaviour of the pattern

Fix these and you get

```
</tr\s*?>\s*(<tr\s*?>.*?</tr\s*?>)\s*<tr\s*?>
```

which will match if there is anything like that in the HTML, and if you have the `DOTALL` option flag set

But, as others have noted, regular expressions aren't the right tool to process HTML. You should use a proper parser